# Is the Steiner surface normal? (Shafarevich pg. 138)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Define the Steiner surface in $\mathbb P^3$ as the zero set of $x_0^2x_1^2 + x_0^2x_2^2 + x_1^2x_2^2 - x_0x_1x_2x_3=0$

> Is this a normal surface?

So it is enough to look at the open affines. I know a criteria that says that if we quotient by $y^2-f$ where f is squarefree polynomial then it is normal domain.

I can't apply it on standard open set $U_3 : x_3=1$ as it is not of this form.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is normal if and only if it has isolated singularities. So, the easiest way to check normality is by computing the singular locus.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the iff condition holds?

Comment: This is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_criterion_for_normality combined with the Cohen-Macaulay property that holds for any complete intersection.